# Cannot get Google AI prediction result using JWT credential using node js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, access-token

I am planning to get AI prediction result using service account and deploy a cloud function to a Firebase project. When trying to get prediction result

https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectid/models/category:predict?

using accesstoken JWT and the result is

```
{ StatusCodeError: 403 - {"error":{"code":403,"message":"Access to model denied.","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}
```

It is confirmed that the service account I'm using has been added to the ML project.

Any idea how to get the ML result in Firebase function using service account? or other method?

Here is the code (I am still newbie to NodeJS)

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const request = require("request");
const requestProm = require("request-promise");

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { GoogleAuth } = require('google-auth-library');

admin.initializeApp();


var reportFld, reportNarTr, reportTitTr;
var input, input2, input3;
var result, predictedHaz, predictedSig, predictedRep, setDoc
var getAccessTokenId

getAccessTokenId = async function main() {
    const auth = new GoogleAuth({        
        scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
    });
    const client = await auth.getClient();
    const projectId = await auth.getProjectId();


    const accessTokenId = await auth.getAccessToken();

    return accessTokenId
}

exports.newReport = functions.firestore
    .document('/users/{usersId}')
    .onCreate((change, context) => {

        const db = admin.firestore();

        const interDoc = db.collection('users').doc(context.params.usersId);
        interDoc.get().then(doc => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
                console.log('No such document!');
            } else {

                var getPrediction
                getPrediction = async function main2() {                    
                    reportFld = doc.data();
                    reportNarTr = JSON.stringify(reportFld.narrative);
                    reportTitTr = JSON.stringify(reportFld.title);
                    reportNumTr = context.params.usersId;

                    input = {
                        instances: [
                            [reportNumTr, reportTitTr, reportNarTr]
                        ]
                    };

                    var accessToken = await getAccessTokenId();


                    var endpointhazCat = 'https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectid/models/hazcat:predict?access_token=' + accessToken;
                    var endpointsigCat = 'https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectid/models/sig:predict?access_token=' + accessToken;
                    var endpointrepCat = 'https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectid/models/type:predict?access_token=' + accessToken;
                    var options1 = {
                        method: 'POST',
                        uri: endpointhazCat,
                        body: input,
                        json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
                    };

                    var options2 = {
                        method: 'POST',
                        uri: endpointsigCat,
                        body: input,
                        json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
                    };

                    var options3 = {
                        method: 'POST',
                        uri: endpointrepCat,
                        body: input,
                        json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
                    };

                    requestProm.post(options1)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            result = response['predictions'];
                            switch (parseInt(result)) {
                                case 0:
                                    predictedHaz = 'A';
                                    break;

                                case 1:
                                    predictedHaz = 'B';
                                    break;

                                case 2:
                                    predictedHaz = 'C';
                                    break;

                                case 3:
                                    predictedHaz = 'D';
                                    break;

                                case 4:
                                    predictedHaz = 'E';
                                    break;

                                case 5:
                                    predictedHaz = 'F';
                                    break;

                                case 6:
                                    predictedHaz = 'G';
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    predictedHaz = 'error';

                            }

                            const predictedHazData = {
                                HazardCategory: predictedHaz,
                            };

                            setDoc = db.collection('users').doc(context.params.usersId).update(predictedHazData);

                            console.log(response);
                            return true
                        })

                        .catch(function (err) {
                            console.log('Failed', err)
                        });


                    requestProm.post(options2)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            result = response['predictions'];
                            if (parseInt(result) > -4) {
                                predictedSig = 'Sig';
                            } else predictedSig = 'Insig'


                            const predictedSigData = {
                                SignifanceCategory: predictedSig,
                            };

                            setDoc = db.collection('users').doc(context.params.usersId).update(predictedSigData);

                            console.log(response);
                            return true
                        })

                        .catch(function (err) {
                            console.log('Failed', err)
                        });


                    requestProm.post(options3)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            result = response['predictions'];
                            if (parseInt(result) === 1) {
                                predictedRep = 'Inc';
                            } else predictedRep = 'Haz'


                            const predictedRepData = {
                                ReportCategory: predictedRep,
                            };

                            setDoc = db.collection('users').doc(context.params.usersId).update(predictedRepData);

                            console.log(response);
                            return true
                        })

                        .catch(function (err) {
                            console.log('Failed', err)
                        });

                    return true
                }

                getPrediction().catch(console.error);
            } return null
        })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('Error getting document', err);
            });

        return true;
    });
```

**Added some details:**

These are the service account permissions:

```
ml.jobs.cancel
ml.jobs.create
ml.jobs.get
ml.jobs.getIamPolicy
ml.jobs.list
ml.jobs.update
ml.locations.get
ml.locations.list
ml.models.create
ml.models.delete
ml.models.get
ml.models.getIamPolicy
ml.models.list
ml.models.predict
ml.models.update
ml.operations.cancel
ml.operations.get
ml.operations.list
ml.projects.getConfig
ml.studies.create
ml.studies.delete
ml.studies.get
ml.studies.getIamPolicy
ml.studies.list
ml.trials.create
ml.trials.delete
ml.trials.get
ml.trials.list
ml.trials.update
ml.versions.create
ml.versions.delete
ml.versions.get
ml.versions.list
ml.versions.predict
ml.versions.update 
resourcemanager.projects.get
```

I have tried to use other node library 'googleapis' on debug console :

```
google.auth.getApplicationDefault((err, authClient, projectId) => {

  if (err) {

    console.log('Authentication failed because of ', err);
    res.status(401).send('Authentication failed');

  } else {

    // create the full model name which includes the project ID
    const modelName = 'projects/ml-project-id/models/hazcat';
    const mlRequestJson = {
      'auth': authClient,
      'name': modelName,
      'resource': { instances: [['RepNum', 'RepTit', 'RepNar']]
          }
    }

    ml.projects.predict(mlRequestJson, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);          
      } else {
          console.log(result.data.predictions[0]);
      }
  }); 
  }
});
```

and the result is:

```
3
```

and deployed to firebase:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const request = require("request");
const requestProm = require("request-promise");
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { GoogleAuth } = require('google-auth-library');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const ml = google.ml('v1');

admin.initializeApp();


var reportFld, reportNarTr, reportTitTr, reportNumTr, reportTitStr, reportNarStr;
var input, input2, input3;
var result, predictedHaz, predictedSig, predictedRep, setDoc


exports.predictReport = functions.firestore
    .document('/users/{usersId}')
    .onCreate((change, context) => {

        const db = admin.firestore();

        const interDoc = db.collection('users').doc(context.params.usersId);
        interDoc.get().then(doc => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
                console.log('No such document!');
            } else {                
                reportFld = doc.data();
                reportNarTr = JSON.stringify(reportFld.narrative);
                reportTitTr = JSON.stringify(reportFld.title);
                reportNumTr = context.params.usersId;

                input = {
                    instances: [
                        [reportNumTr, reportTitTr, reportNarTr]
                    ]
                };

                var result1, result2, result3

                google.auth.getApplicationDefault((err, authClient, projectId) => {

                    if (err) {

                        console.log('Authentication failed because of ', err);
                        res.status(401).send('Authentication failed');

                    } else {

                        const modelName = 'projects/ml-project-id/models/hazcat';
                        const modelName2 = 'projects/ml-project-id/models/sig';
                        const modelName3 = 'projects/ml-project-id/models/type';

                        const mlRequestJson1 = {
                            'auth': authClient,
                            'name': modelName,
                            'resource': input
                        }

                        const mlRequestJson2 = {
                            'auth': authClient,
                            'name': modelName2,
                            'resource': input
                        }

                        const mlRequestJson3 = {
                            'auth': authClient,
                            'name': modelName3,
                            'resource': input
                        }
                        var result1, result2, result3
                        ml.projects.predict(mlRequestJson1, (err, result) => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);

                            } else {

                                console.log(result.data.predictions[0]);
                                result1 = result.data.predictions[0];
                                switch (parseInt(result1)) {
                                    case 0:
                                        predictedHaz = 'A';
                                        break;

                                    case 1:
                                        predictedHaz = 'B';
                                        break;

                                    case 2:
                                        predictedHaz = 'C';
                                        break;

                                    case 3:
                                        predictedHaz = 'D';
                                        break;

                                    case 4:
                                        predictedHaz = 'E';
                                        break;

                                    case 5:
                                        predictedHaz = 'F';
                                        break;

                                    case 6:
                                        predictedHaz = 'G';
                                        break;

                                    default:
                                        predictedHaz = 'error';

                                }

                                const predictedHazData = {
                                    HazardCategory: predictedHaz,
                                };
                                setDoc = db.collection('users').doc(context.params.usersId).update(predictedHazData);
                            }
                        }); // endof predict1

                        ml.projects.predict(mlRequestJson2, (err, result) => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);                                
                            } else {                                
                                console.log(result.data.predictions[0]);
                                result2 = result.data.predictions[0];

                                if (parseInt(result2) > -4) {
                                    predictedSig = 'Sig';
                                } else predictedSig = 'Insig'


                                const predictedSigData = {
                                    SignifanceCategory: predictedSig,
                                };

                                setDoc = db.collection('users').doc(context.params.usersId).update(predictedSigData);

                            }
                        });// endof predict2

                        ml.projects.predict(mlRequestJson3, (err, result) => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);

                            } else {                                
                                console.log(result.data.predictions[0]);
                                result3 = result.data.predictions[0];

                                if (parseInt(result3) === 1) {
                                    predictedRep = 'Inc';
                                } else predictedRep = 'Haz'


                                const predictedRepData = {
                                    ReportCategory: predictedRep,
                                };

                                setDoc = db.collection('users').doc(context.params.usersId).update(predictedRepData);
                            }
                        });// endof predict3
                    }//endof else getappdefault
                });//endof getappdefault
            } return true
        })//endof getdocument
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('Error getting document', err);
            });
        return true;
    });//endof onCreate
```

and the result is

```
Authentication failed because of  Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
    at AuthPlus.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/srv/node_modules/googleapis-common/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:156:23)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

**Added details (update 2)**
I have used keyfile pointing to service account json file.

```
getAccessTokenId = async function main() {    
    const auth = new GoogleAuth({
        keyFile: 'projectid.json',
        scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
    });    
    const client = await auth.getClient();
    const projectId = await auth.getProjectId();
    const accessTokenId = await auth.getAccessToken();    
    return accessTokenId
}
```

got access token like this

```
ya29.c.xxxx
```

and the permission denied

```
Failed { StatusCodeError: 403 - {"error":{"code":403,"message":"Access to model denied.","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}
```

**Added details (update 3)**
I'm using my personal credentials to enter the ML model works inside cloud function

```
getAccessTokenId = async function main() {    
        const auth = new GoogleAuth({        
        keyFile: 'application_default_credentials.json',
        scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
    });
    const client = await auth.getClient();
    const projectId = await auth.getProjectId();
    const accessTokenId = await auth.getAccessToken();
    return accessTokenId
}
```

Get the result

```
{ predictions: [ 3 ] }
```

I also have added Service Account Token Creator role on the service account but still not work using service account to access ML Model

```
iam.serviceAccountKeys.create
iam.serviceAccountKeys.delete
iam.serviceAccountKeys.get
iam.serviceAccountKeys.list
```

But curious why it doesnt have these

```
iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken
iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob
iam.serviceAccounts.signJwt
iam.serviceAccounts.implicitDelegation
iam.serviceAccounts.getOpenIdToken
```

Comment: What permissions does the service account has on the ML project? Make sure that is has at least the [Developer Role assigned](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/access-control#developer_role).  Share the results of running `gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy your-service-account-name@your-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com` by removing any personal identifiable information (such as project id, etc) to [view the permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#viewing-roles) assigned to the service account.

Comment: Also make sure that the API is enabled at the project. Running `gcloud services enable ml.googleapis.com --project=[ML-project-id]` should do the trick.

Comment: The API has been enabled, because I tried it in debug console and the ML gave prediction results. When it was deployed, it was denied

Comment: Hi @DanielOcando shared the permissions on the editted question

Comment: Did you define the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable pointing to the credentials.json file of the service account as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable) ?

Comment: I have defined that. When using application default credential in my local machine, it gave access token and use that token worked. But when deploy to firebase, it gave access token `ya29.c.xxxxx` (I think it is JWT) and the permission was denied.

Comment: After looking at the code, I was not able to see where you refers to the service account as such (which should be either putting an explicit path to where the credentials.json of the service account is or defining a variable env that points to the path where that file is). Could you please point me out where are you doing the previous?

Comment: And also please assign the service account the Service Account Token Creator role (because from what I see from the code it is the service account that is generating the tokens)

Comment: I defined the service account json as environment variable in terminal `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=[PATH]`

Comment: @NibrassH I have pointed out explicitly the service account json as described on the updated question above. It was denied also. Could it be IAM role in the ML project issue?

Comment: Thanks @KayAndrian, could you please try to use an another service account with the permissions that import those ML.predict and the same permissions of the Service Account and let me know if it works or not? Yes, please also try to add IAm role for [ML](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#primitive_role_definitions).

Comment: Also Try to assign first owner role to your project, and try again, if it works, then we will narrow down the issue to the permissions, and will continue to find the correct permissions to get AI result in Cloud Functions.

Comment: Hi @NibrassH using other service account works after assign it as ML model user as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/sharing-models)

Comment: Hi, @Kay Andiran, Thanks for letting me know, so now we know that it was a permissions issue. Did you try to use the other service account with Ml model permissions ? Does it work or still giving issues?